# How to get an Azure MSI access token for a specific user assigned identity on a VM/VMSS?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I'd like to assign multiple user assigned managed service identities to a VM Scale Set in Azure. I can do so by following the [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/qs-configure-powershell-windows-vmss#user-assigned-identity).

What I have not figured out yet is how I can request a token for a specific identity.The docs for [requesting a token via the IMDS endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-http) do not mention any request parameters for specifying e.g. a clientId.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian,

You can request tokens for a particular managed identity, by passing in the client_id or object_id in the request. For example: `curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/&object_id=<USERASSIGNED_OBJECT_ID>' -H Metadata:true -s`

Our docs are being updated right now to properly include this info. Thanks for the note! :)

-Arturo

Comment: Hey Arturo, looks like the parameter is client_id now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview . Will object_id still work?  Can you update your post please?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without the use of a VM? I have a data factory which has a managed identity assigned to it and I'd like to be able to access https://management.azure.com/

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers provide the right pointer.

If you are using Azure SDKs to write your code, then you can use Azure.Identity library and the DefaultAzureCredential object as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#specifying-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-with-the-defaultazurecredential